# How to locate this input field in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is the html code of the page. I need to input some text in username field.
 How do i do it ?

```
<div class="login_cred">
<label>Username*</label>
<input id="username" name="userName" tabindex="12" size="30" maxlength="30" 
onfocus="getFocus(this.id);" autocomplete="off" oncopy="return false" 
onpaste="return false" onkeypress="return disableCtrlKeyCombination(event);" 
onkeydown="return disableCtrlKeyCombination(event);" type="text">
<label>Password*</label>
<input id="label2" name="password" tabindex="13" title="password" size="30" 
onfocus="getFocus(this.id);" autocomplete="off" oncopy="return false" 
onpaste="return false" onkeypress="return disableCtrlKeyCombination(event);" 
onkeydown="return disableCtrlKeyCombination(event);" type="password">
<br>   
<br>
```

I tried following code and it is giving an error saying element not found

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='username']")).sendKeys("qa");
```

Comment: do you have more then one input having username tag or do you have frame tag as parent of this code snippet

Comment: can you provide URL?

Comment: https://retail.onlinesbi.com/retail/login.htm

Comment: yes there are 2 input tags. One for Username and other for password.

Comment: are you clicking on Login button before entering username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below :-

```
driver.get("https://retail.onlinesbi.com/retail/login.htm");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(.,'CONTINUE TO LOGIN')])[2]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='username']")).sendKeys("test");
```

Full code :-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Workspace\\FluentWaitTest\\src\\lib\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://retail.onlinesbi.com/retail/login.htm");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(.,'CONTINUE TO LOGIN')])[2]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='username']")).sendKeys("test");
```

If still not work then their can be some frame or other tag present which same attributes

Comment: it didnt work. It is still giving same error:     'Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to
 locate element: //input[@name='userName' and @id='userName']'.    Website is https://retail.onlinesbi.com/retail/login.htm.

Comment: I am getting below error. Am i doing something wrong ? I am using firefox driver. INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Expecte
d [object Undefined] undefined to be a string
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'

Comment: Can you update your firfox and gecko driver. because in my side the code is working correctly

Comment: your d object not defined.. share your full code you are using. or use my shared code it will work

Comment: Thanks Shubham, it worked like a magic ! The issue is with FF. With Chrome it works fine ! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the cause that the element are not loaded when you are trying to open the url http://retail.onlinesbi.com/retail/login.htm. You have to click **CONTINUE TO LOGIN** button first then you get your input boxes.